# Data insert codeignetter throwing error

Tags: codeigniter

> PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   property: Registerform::$db Filename: core/Model.php Line Number: 51
>   controller file:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Registerform::$db

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 51

> controller file:

```
<?php
class Registerform extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Registerform_model');
    }

    public function index() {

        //$this->load->database();

        $this->load->helper("form");
        $this->load->library("form_validation");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("first", "First Name","required");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("last", "Last Name","required");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "Email Address","required|valid_email");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "Password","required");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("phone", "Phone Number","required");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("city", "City","required");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("addrss", " Your Address","required");
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $this->load->view("registerform_view");
        } else {
            $first = $_POST["first"];
            $last = $_POST["last"];
            $email = $_POST["email"];
            $password = $_POST["password"];
            $phone = $_POST["phone"];
            $city = $_POST["city"];
            $addrss = $_POST["addrss"];
            $data = array(
                      'first'=>$first,
                      'last'=>$last,
                      'email'=>$email,
                      'password'=>$password,
                      'phone'=>$phone,
                      'city'=>$city,
                      'addrss'=>$addrss
             );                       

            //$data="insert into address (first_name,last_name,email,password,phone,city,add) values('$first','$last','$email','$password','$phone','$city','$add')";

             $gg = $this->Registerform_model->insert_address($data);
             echo $gg;
             $this->load->view("registerformsuccess");

        }
    }
}
?>
```

model file:

```
<?php
class Registerform_model extends CI_Model {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function insert_address($data){                  
        $this->db->insert("address", $data);                    
    }
}
?>
```

view file:

```
<?php               
echo validation_errors();           
echo form_open("Registerform");
?>
<label for="first">First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="first" id="first"><br>

<label for="last">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="last" id="last"><br>

<label for="email">Email Address</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>

<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br>

<label for="phone">Phone</label>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"><br>

<label for="city">City Name</label>
<input type="text" name="city" id="city"><br>

<label for="addrss">Your Address</label>
<input type="text" name="addrss" id="addrss"><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: you should change all your `$_POST` to CI's `$this->input-post()`

Comment: is `address` spelled the right way?. Can you provide your MySql data structure?

Comment: You have not loaded your database.

Comment: Your not loading your database as @Joerg suggest's. go to `application/config/autoload.php` and make sure you have it set to autoload `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database')`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
class Registerform_model extends CI_Model {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        }
           public function insert_address($data){   
                 $this->load->database();               
        $this->db->insert("address", $data);                    
    }
        }
?>
```

Its work for me now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load database.
Put this line in model file constructor function:

```
 $this->load->database();
```